# Where is the IBuffer byte[].AsBuffer extension method?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime

During build they mentioned that to get an IBuffer, there's an extension method on byte arrays called AsBuffer(). Unfortunately they didn't mention what namespace it's hiding in, and doesn't seem to be in the many I've added. Has anyone found where it's hiding at?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The namespace is `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`.

VS Object Browser is your friend here - just be sure to set the framework switcher accordingly. For .NET libraries available in Metro apps, you want ".NET Framework Core 4.5".

Comment: I didn't know you could actually search in the object browser, thanks!

Comment: Worth knowing also: these extension methods will largely only work with non-managed implementations of IBuffer and MS's own WindowsRuntimeBuffer. User supplied managed IBuffer implementations will fail an internal cast. I haven't been able to force type equivalency between mine and their IBufferByteAccess declaration..